# How To Hide ID From URL Path in Angular 9

Tags: angular, url

Actually, I want to hide ID from the URL.
I have single page design to display different kinds of category pages.

For example, the industry has a single page and chemical, agriculture, food has different pages which have assigned id from DB.

**My URL display as http://localhost:4200/reports/20/agriculture

and I want to display as http://localhost:4200/agriculture**

Here is my code

header.component.html

```
<a class="dropdown">
  <span type="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Industries
    </span>
     <div class="dropdown-menu">
                           
      <a  (click)="send_id(20,'agriculture')"  class="dropdown-item cc px-3 py-1">Agriculture & Agrochemicals</a>
      <a  (click)="send_id(17,'automotive')"  class="dropdown-item cc px-3 py-1">Automotive, Aerospace & Defence</a>
      <a  (click)="send_id(1,'chemical-material')"  class="dropdown-item cc px-3 py-1">Chemicals & Materials</a>
      <a  (click)="send_id(6,'consumer-goods-packaging')"  class="dropdown-item cc px-3 py-1">Consumer Goods & Packaging</a>
      <a  (click)="send_id(2,'energy-mining-infra')"  class="dropdown-item cc px-3 py-1">Energy, Infrastructure and Mining</a>
      <a  (click)="send_id(3,'food-beverage')"  class="dropdown-item cc px-3 py-1">Food & Beverages</a>
      <a  (click)="send_id(4,'healthcare-medical-devices')"  class="dropdown-item cc px-3 py-1">Healthcare & Medical Devices</a>
      <a  (click)="send_id(5,'ict-semiconductor')"  class="dropdown-item cc px-3 py-1">Electronics, ICT & Semiconductors</a>
      <a (click)="send_id(18,'industry-automation')"  class="dropdown-item cc px-3 py-1">Industry Automation</a></div>
</a>
```

header.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import { ApiService } from '../services/api.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private activeroute: ActivatedRoute, private api: ApiService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  send_id(id: any, no: any) {
    this.router.navigate(['/reports', id, no])
      .then(() => {
        window.location.reload();
      });
  }
}
```

rounting:

```
const routes: Routes = [{ path: 'RD/:id/:no/:sr', component: industryComponent }]
```

Comment: You can use a service to set the current id and access that in the industryComponent

Comment: you can use BehaviourSubject in Service and Subscribe it to the another component, in this case you can avoid use of ID.

Comment: can you show with some examples?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can implement a solution for this, yo can get the URL parameter and after that, you can clean the history with `window.history.pushState`.

in the ngOnInit of the final navigation page, this could be an implementation:

```
ngOnInit(){
 const queryString = window.location.search;
 const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
 const id= urlParams.get('id')
 window.history.pushState({}, document.title, "/" + "reports");
}
```